# como fazer pra pesquisar o codigo certo? pois quando cadastro um codigo, na hora da pesquisa digito qualquer valor e da o produto que cadastrei

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<locale.h>

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Portuguese");
        
    struct cadastro
    {
        char nome[50], fornecedor[50];
        int cod_cadastro, cod_pesquisa;
    };
    struct cadastro produto;
    
    int opc;
    
    do{     
    printf("\t\t\t#######################\n");
    printf("\t\t\t#                     #\n");
    printf("\t\t\t# CADASTRO DE PRODUTO #\n");
    printf("\t\t\t#                     #\n");
    printf("\t\t\t#  1 - CADASTRAR      #\n");
    printf("\t\t\t#  2 - PESQUISAR      #\n");
    printf("\t\t\t#  3 - SAIR           #\n");
    printf("\t\t\t#                     #\n");
    printf("\t\t\t#######################\n");
    
    printf("\nSELECIONE UMA OPÇÃO: ");
    scanf("%d",&opc);
    fflush(stdin);
    system("cls");
    
    switch(opc)
    {
        
        case 1:
            printf("novo codigo: ");
            scanf("%d",&produto.cod_cadastro); printf("\n");
            fflush(stdin);
            printf("nome do produto: ");
            scanf(" %[^\n]",produto.nome);  printf("\n");
            fflush(stdin);
            printf("fornecedor: ");
            scanf(" %[^\n]",produto.fornecedor); printf("\n");
            fflush(stdin);
            printf("....gravado com sucesso!\n\n");
            
            break;
        case 2:
            printf("digite o codigo do produto: ");
            scanf("%d",&produto.cod_pesquisa);
            fflush(stdin);
            system("cls");  
                    
            printf("== PRODUTO ==\n\n");
            printf("codigo fornecido: %d",produto.cod_pesquisa); printf("\n");
            printf("Produto: %s",produto.nome); printf("\n");
            printf("Fornecedor: %s",produto.fornecedor); printf("\n\n\n");          
            break;
    }
    system("pause");
    system("cls");
}while(opc!=3);
    
    
    
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Pesquisar onde? Você sempre terá apenas um produto no seu código.

Comment: Mas você não verifica nada! Nem se é ou não o único produto cadastrado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adicione mais uma variavel exclusivamente para pegar o código digitado

```
int id_digitado = 0;
```

Então substitua a variavel que recebe o código informado

```
printf("digite o codigo do produto: ");
scanf("%d",&id_digitado);
```

Por fim, só escreva no console os dados do produto caso o id_digitado seja igual ao produto.cod_pesquisa

```
if(id_digitado == produto.cod_pesquisa){
   printf("== PRODUTO ==\n\n");
   printf("codigo fornecido: %d",produto.cod_pesquisa); printf("\n");
   printf("Produto: %s",produto.nome); printf("\n");
   printf("Fornecedor: %s",produto.fornecedor); printf("\n\n\n");          
 }  
 break;
```